# How a comparator works?

Tags: java, comparator

I was studying collections in Java and in between, I got stuck at the comparator. In the code below :

```
class MyComp implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        String aStr, bStr;
        aStr = a;
        bStr = b;
        // Reverse the comparison.
        return bStr.compareTo(aStr);
       }
       // No need to override equals.
      }
class CompDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Create a tree set.
    TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComp());
    // Add elements to the tree set.
    ts.add("C");
    ts.add("A");
    ts.add("B");
    ts.add("E");
    ts.add("F");
    ts.add("D");
    // Display the elements.
    for(String element : ts)
    System.out.print(element + " ");
    System.out.println();
   }
  }
```

1. I am not able to understand is `public int compare(String a, String b)` at line number 2 overrided? Also, what `TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComp())` line means?
2. I read that

> The Comparator interface defines two methods: compare( ) and equals( ).

then how **compareTo()** is used.

3. How are the elements getting reversed?

If anyone has an answer regarding any point which I have described above, please go on.

Comment: Did you try googling "What is a Comparator in java?" or "what is a TreeSet in java?"

Comment: *"Also, what `TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComp())` line means"* For that you should read the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)

Comment: *"I am not able to understand is `public int compare(String a, String b)` at line number 2 overrided?"* Java `Comparator` used to have only one method, things are more complicated now.  It's this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)

Comment: Yes, it explained same as I had read in my book, I had not found the relatable and to the point answer in that.

Comment: ok, I will go through this link. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A treeset is a sortedset, i.e. it sorts the elements within the treeset. Now, how does it sort? It uses the comparator. i.e., somewhere in the code, it does a comparison using it.

```
    int cmp;
    Entry<K,V> parent;
    // split comparator and comparable paths
    Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
    if (cpr != null) {
        do {
            parent = t;
            cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                t = t.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                t = t.right;
            else
                return t.setValue(value);
        } while (t != null);
    }
```

This is from the TreeSet source code.

Answer (score 0):

compare(a,b) works like this:

Return a negative integer if a is "lower than" b.
Return 0 if a "equals" b.
Return a positive integer if a is "greater than" b.

Depending on your Comparator type you shall define what "lower than" , "equals" and "greater than" mean.

Example:

```
public class Person {
private int id;
private String name;

public Person(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}}

public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
@Override public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
    if(o1.getId() == o2.getId()) return 0;
    else if(o1.getId() < o2.getId()) return -1;
    else return 1;
    // can be replaced by Integer.compare
}}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start one by one,
Comparator is a way of comparing two objects of some generic type

In general, Comparator can deal with Java wrappers [Integer, Double, Character...], but sometimes when it comes to more complicated forms of objects, it is not suitable at all
Let's say for example we have an object called Time and it got (Hour, minute, second)
And we want to sort these objects but here we cant use the default `compare(T a, T b)` that is implemented as we said it can deal with a certain category of objects
This where comes the part where we have to implement the Comparator interface and override compare with the one that can deal with our situation
For example for Time object we can do it as follows so we can sort these objects:

```
 public class TimeComparator implements Comparator<Time2> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Time2 time1, Time2 time2) {
        int hourDifference = time1.getHour() - time2.getHour();

        if (hourDifference != 0) { // test the hour first
            return hourDifference;
        }

        int minuteDifference = time1.getMinute() - time2.getMinute();

        if (minuteDifference != 0) { // then test the minute
            return minuteDifference;
        }

        int secondDifference = time1.getSecond() - time2.getSecond();
        return secondDifference;
    }
```

}

---

> then how compareTo() is used.

compareTo is a method that exists in class Comparable that can be used in such a different way as it takes one generic type and compares it to your referenced value(Not sure if that's the correct way to describe it)

```
a.compareTo(T b)
```

---

> TreeSet ts = new TreeSet(new MyComp());

A TreeSet is an ordered set without duplicates that uses the default Comparator of generics when it's not provided
As you can see in TreeSet constructor javadocs

> ```
> TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
> Constructs a new, empty tree set, sorted according to the specified comparator.
> ```

This means your TreeSet will be sorted according to whatever comparator you have provided instead of the default implemented one

Comparator is also used as an easy way to use Collections.sort static method

> ```
> sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
> Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

String class  implements comparable interface

wrapper classes implements both comparable and comparator

Comparator decouples sorting logic from the Class we defined.
  Comparable is bind to the class and we can only perform sorting on only one field.

## Answers:

comparision happens between Characters (String is group of characters) or between Numbers

when you implement compare method ,if you are comparing 2 Strings then you have to call compareTo(..) method (this compareTo() method is implemented to compare each character .i,e ex: String name1 = sam ,String name2 = joe, if you call name1.compareTo(name2) s is compared against j,a is compared against o and m is compared against e. Since s is not equal to j further comparison won't continue and returns -ve value bcz ascii value of s is less that ascii value of j.

if you are comparing 2 numbers you can directly compare then with '==' or can call compareTo(..) by wrapping. And return +ve,-ve or 0 based on the comparison .

Like this Comparision continues until all elements are compared.

each time you add elements to a tree or any collection, comparison happens and keep sorting until all elements added and finished.

equals() method is there in Object class so you don't need to implement it. Which will be inherited by default.